# I get a syntax error about File "<stdin>", line 1

Tags: python, syntax-error

This is the error, I have no idea where the fault is:

[image]

```
> & C:/Users/tanel/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe  
"c:/Users/tanel/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/Game Alien/game.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/tanel/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/tanel/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/Game Alien/game.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're getting a Python `SyntaxError` because you are trying to run a PowerShell command in the Python shell:

```
>>> & C:/Users/tanel/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/tanel/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/Game Alien/game.py"
```

`exit()` out of that shell and then run your PowerShell command in PowerShell. The prompt should look something like

```
PS C:\>
```

The Python shell is for running code interactively, e.g. you could type something like `import pygame` or `print("Hello, world!")` directly into it.

Comment: Just enter ctrl+z and hit enter hopefully will solved the issue

Comment: @HassanShamshir, yes that will work too (on Windows, at least). `exit()` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because you are most likely in the python shell. When this happened to me I switched to the PowerShell and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in short You must exit the python shell. For example, in order to do that on Vs Code You can use the built in command `Ctrl+D`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).