# Cannot run Python Script inside VSCODE terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

However simple my python script is, I cannot get it running inside VSCODE Terminal by clicking on the "RUN" icon at the top right, whereas it runs fine when called from a CMD window

[image]

Comment: What's the `&` for there?

Comment: No idea, I just click on the Run button

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this thread helped me [I get a syntax error about File "<stdin>", line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505167/i-get-a-syntax-error-about-file-stdin-line-1)

You are now working inside your Python shell (>>>) while the code you are running (& python "FILENAME.py") is no Python, therefore syntax error.

```
    exit()
```

to exit the python shell and return to the PowerShell environment.

Simply

```
    python
```

to enter again, to run python code directly

Comment: Thanks. I will try it again. The fact is the python was incorrectly declared inside vscode. I had to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems python is not recognized in your PATH variable. I think the 2 ways to fix are to find your python filepath and adding it your User Variables:

- Control panel > System > advanced settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables
- select PATH and then click edit..
- in a new line add the path to your python installation (ie C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32)

OR, not sure this works out of the box but you could:

- install Python module from within VS Code, published by Microsoft

Comment: Thx, I have done that already, and it is working OK inside a CMD window

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is VS code recognizing the version of Python you're using (bottom left of purple bar)?

Comment: Yes, indeed, once restarted

Answer (score 0):

After editing the PATH as suggested by @mah111, I needed to restart VSCODE application